# How to architect this node.js and angular app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, angularjs-service

I'm pretty new to javascript, node and angular but have coded a lot in java before. I have been reading up for quite some time on services, factory, module, controllers and detectives but need some help.

I want to run a task every midnight to pull a json object and parse it.

I want to display the parsed data on the front end. It's a few timestamps and I have figured out how to print variables on html.

I need to run another task 5 times a day on the timestamps returned by the json object to play a sound.

How do I go about designing my application?  I can currently create modules and controllers but I feel like this logic needs to be In a service or a factory but I'm not sure.

Alternatively,  I have this logic coded in python and it works but I would like to keep my code clean and run it in angular/node. Your help architecting is appreciated. I can read and figure out how to program the rest

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the part where you need to "schedule" this task to run 5 times a day, but here's an idea on how you can show the data in the front end:
Use the concept of Observables.
When you create you page, you can create an Observable. This Observable will be listening for a event from the backend. Once the backend emits the event, the Observable will notify all Objects that are subscribed to it. Then you can use the return with a ngIf directive to display a message in the frontend.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to understand my situation and sharing feedback. The app pulls a json with instructions that need to be carried out at specific times. Every midnight, it would check for instructions for the following day. It would print out all the instructions and times on the screen and when it's time for the task to be carried out, it would make a sound to notify users that it's time to carry out their assigned tasks.

Comment: It's basically getting instructions every midnight, displaying on screen and sounding an alarm when it's time.

Comment: Where do I write the code to say when it's time, do this task. Would that be in a controller or factory or a service?

Comment: @Bilal ... You can use both! In the component(or components) that holds the screen to be updated, you can have a variable that is subscribed to the service ... You can make the service keep asking you backend from time to time if the task is completed, when the return is positive , the service will notify all the components that are subscribed to it! If you have any more questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: I would love to get some help from you with my code if you have some time. My email is bmalik4444@gmail.com